# Can someone help me t understand this PHP code

Tags: php, explode

I am working from an existing project and hit a road block

I am trying to understand the following

```
$list = "" . substr($data, $start,$length) . "";
$new_list = explode("|" , $list);
```

Yes $start and $length are set, that is not the concern.

I need to try to understand the "double double quotes dot" and "dot double double quotes" and their implications on the php explode command that follows.

Is this simply saying that $list contents will be like this?

```
" . <Content here> . "
```

I did not think concatenate "." was ever used with double quotes.

Thanks for any help

Comment: `$list = substr($data, $start,$length);` will give you the same result. You can read more about strings [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Btw, you should remove the last paragraph. Complaining about the people you're asking to help you doesn't seem that nice. Specially when you do it before anyone have even down voted or voted to close the question. Also, this site has guidelines. If you ask questions that are off-topic, they _should_ be closed. It's your responsibility to read the guidelines before posting.

Comment: In the posted code, it will make no difference. [Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/9DDDY). If there's an issue somewhere else because if this, you need to share that code and explain what the issue is. The `$new_list` will be identical with or without the quotes.

Comment: I removed the complaining from your question. Questions are for your issue, not for venting.

Comment: As someone who has voted to close a previous question, not sure if you want my input.  BUT with some content, `$list = "".$b;` will force `$b` to be cast to a string, whereas `$list = $b;` will not.  So it can affect the data type being used, but as you already have `substr()` in there, it shouldn't make much difference.  You may need to add more context to help resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

dot is only for concatination of string. 
double double quotes  is empty string.

explode makes an array from string.

```
$list = "aaaa|bbbb|cccc";
$new_list = explode("|" , $list);
```

Result:

```
array("aaaa","bbbb","cccc");
```

look at php.net. there are samples too.

Comment: Why would the explode command give different output without the double quotes dot? And why would someone then concatenate with the empty string beginning and end?

Comment: @TeknoGeekz - Who said it would give you different results? In this case, it won't make any difference. However, if you would do: `$foo = "" . 123 . "";` vs `$foo = 123;` there will be a difference. The first would give you a string `"123"` (since you're concatenating the int with strings) while the second would give you an int `123`.

Comment: @TeknoGeekz double qutoes marking the start and end of a string.

Comment: @TeknoGeekz i suppose you should explain how you define `$scansupportedresolutions` in your previous [closed] post since that's seems to be your actual substr param, and you don't seem to be understanding with all the good advice you're getting.